# SharePoint Search issues after replacing WFE server

Tags: sharepoint, search

We have a small intranet installation of MOSS SP2 with a single WFE and a separate SQL Server.

I recently switched out the old WFE server that was running Windows Server 2003 Standard 32-bit, the process I followed was the following:

- Bring up a new server running Windows Server 2008 Standard x64
- Install MOSS x64 (didn't run SharePoint Configuration Wizard)
- Patch the server to the same SharePoint patch level as the other WFE (SP2)
- Run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard to add the server to the farm
- Change our DNS to point to the new server
- Run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard **on the old WFE** to remove it from the farm

Up until this point, everything worked as expected.  I started the Office SharePoint Server Search and the Windows SharePoint Services Search services on the WFE.

However, search wasn't working in the farm.  When I browsed to the SSP and went into Search Settings, I got the following error:

> Could not connect to search application for 'SharedServices1' on server WFESERVERNAME. This error might occur if the Application Server Administration Service Timer Job does not exist. Confirm that the Windows SharePoint Services Timer service and Windows SharePoint Services Administration service are running on the affected server. If the problem persists, view the event logs on the affected server for more information.

I looked at the Timer Job Definitions and we don't have a Timer Job called **Application Server Administration Service**.

I verified that all the services are started in the Services console on the server, and running with the appropriate credentials.  I followed the steps in this KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934838/en-us to verify that the correct credentials were being used for all the services.

Any tips on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: When you say that the services were all started - did you also ensure that the "Windows Sharepoint Services Administration" and "Windows Sharepoint Services Timer" services actually existed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No .. you cannot re-create the deleted global timer job . the best would be create new configuration database

Cheers

Comment: I spent a few hours on the phone yesterday with Microsoft support, and the resolution was to recreate our configuration database ... Not as bad as I thought, everything is up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

Look under Administrative Tools > Services, and see if the **Windows SharePoint Services Timer** service is started.

Comment: The Windows SharePoint Services Timer service is started